# JS: grid of images and onclick event

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new with JS and this is my first post here...
I'm trying to have a grid of images (all the same) and I need that when the user click on one of them, a function is executed.
Hope my code isn't a mess:

```
cellWidth = 42;
cellHeight = 42;
rownumber = 10;
columnnumber = 15;
leftmargin = 500;
topmargin = 150;

for (var i = 0; i < rownumber; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < columnnumber; x++) {
    var cell = new Image();
    cell.src = "black.png";
    cell.style.position = "absolute";
    cell.id = x+"x"+i;
    cell.style.left = x * cellWidth + leftmargin - cellWidth*i;
    cell.style.top = i * cellHeight + topmargin;
    cell.onclick=function(){alert("Hello World")};
    document.body.appendChild(cell);
}   
}
```

I've tried with `cell.addEventListener` too, but nothing happened.

EDIT: somehow, it happens to work correctly on firefox.
Is there something wrong with my code or with my browser?!?!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me...the problem might be where you're putting the script.  If you put it in the `<head>` section, it won't work as written because `document.body` doesn't exist yet.  Try putting at the end of the `<body>` element.  In other words:

```
<head>
    <script>
        // document.body will be null
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // document.body good to go
    </script>
</body>
```

If this was the problem, you should have seen a console log message about it.  For example, in Chrome, if you put this script in the `<head>` section, you'll see the following error message on the console output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null
```

Which should be a clue about where the problem is.  Whenever you have a problem *always* look at the console first: it may tell you exactly what you need to know.

Comment: Nope...I have already put it inside the body...
Furthermore the console is completely mute!

EDIT: what the...it works on firefox!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry.
I've tried on chrome and firefox and it works only on firefox. It does not on chrome.

Comment: What are you seeing in Chrome?  Blank document?  Are there any console errors?

Comment: i have the grid, without any alert. no console errors.

Comment: You have the grid?  Isn't the code supposed to make the grid?  So what, exactly, isn't working?